# How to convert .pdf file to .png using Imagemagick PHP API

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want to convert .pdf file to .png file using Imagemagick php API.

we can do this from shell using this:

`$convert sample.pdf sample_image.png`

we can issue this command using php `exec()` function but due to some reason (security) I disabled the execution of shell commands using php.

so now tell me the solution that how can i convert my .pdf file to .png file without using the php `exec()` function?

There is another discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588918/imagemagick-imagick-convert-pdf-to-jpg-using-native-php-api) but it's not very clear.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you must have installed php5-imagick

```
$myurl = 'filename.pdf['.$pagenumber.']';
$image = new Imagick($myurl);
$image->setResolution( 300, 300 );
$image->setImageFormat( "png" );
$image->writeImage('newfilename.png');
```

Comment: This works great for me, except it throws an exception in writeImage. header("Content-type image/png"); echo $image; solves the problem.

Comment: I have no Idea anymore. ImageMagick 6.8.8-9 is installed but I don't get any image from my pdf. If I change `$myurl = 'filename.pdf['.$pagenumber.']'` to an image I get a new image with the name `$image->writeImage('newfilename.png');` as expected. But I get nothing from my pdf. Maybe someone has any Idea what could go wrong.

Comment: You need to set the resolution before you read the image. Just FYI.

Comment: setResolution() must be used before the file read, hence use readImage() to get the file after Imagic initialization  in the order  `$image = new Imagick(); $image->setResolution( 30, 30); $image->readImage($myurl); `

Answer (score 1):

> but due to some reason(security) i disabled the execution of shell commands using php

You'll either need to re-enable the execution of shell commands, or install the [ImageMagick PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) on how to install it.

Comment: ImageMagick PHP extension is already installed but i need some simple example code for the solution of my problem,so please explain it with a PHP code example.