# Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file'

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm running PHP 5.4.30 with imagick module 3.1.0RC2. phpinfo() does show the module as loaded and phpinfo() shows PDF as a supported format.

When running:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('./test.pdf');
```

I receive:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file: ./test.pdf'`

When I change the image type to be a JPEG and read `'./test.jpg'` No errors are returned. Permissions have been check and different PDFs have been tested. I have inserted the absolute path to the image with an exception still being thrown. The images are for this example placed in the same directory alongside the script.
What am I missing?

Comment: Where are those test images located in the file system? To what absolute path should the replative path `./test.pdf` expand?

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. As command line it worked perfectly fine: `convert book.pdf book.jpeg` but pdf didn't seem to work. If not, you may want to install GhostScript
I found the solution on the issue [588918](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588918/imagemagick-imagick-convert-pdf-to-jpg-using-native-php-api). You simply have to create a symlink of `gs` (the GhostScript library) in `usr/bin`. Basically, If you do something like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs-noX11 /usr/bin/gs
```

and restart your server it should work. At least it did for me.